# Is it possible to output http-logging through nlog?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nlog

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0
Following the above link, I tried to use the http logging.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseNLog(); 

var app = builder. Build();
    
app.UseHttpLogging();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

However I cannot see the http log in my log file defined in nlog.config

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/HTTP-Request-Logging#usehttplogging-introduced-with-net6

Answer (score 2):

```
<rules>
    <!--Output Http logging -->
    <logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware" minlevel="Info" writeTo="httpLog" final="true"/>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" maxlevel="Warn" writeTo="traceLog" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="errorLog,console" />
```

Once I moved the logger as the first in the rule set, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The possible problem could be the logging level being set to higher than info. You should also make sure that the following configuration is in the app settings file:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware": "Information"
```